# Finding the number of 1s connected to 5 or more other 1s (e.g. neighbours) in a number of csv files

Tags: r

I have wrote the below function to find the number of 1s with only one other connecting 1.

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
files <- lapply(temp, read.table)

number_1_neighbour <- function(x) { 
   check_diff <- diff(x) == 0
   (c(0,check_diff) + c(check_diff,0)) * x 
}

neigh1_rows_columns <- lapply(files, function(y) sum(t(apply(y, 1, 
number_1_neighbour)) + apply(y, 2, number_1_neighbour) == 1))
```

How would I update this code to check for 1s that have 5 or more connected 1s?

For example in a matrix such as...

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

There would be 4 1s connected by 5 or more other 1s as neighbours.

A reproducible example,

```
set.seed(99) 
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 2500, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow=50)
mat

set.seed(1234)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 2500, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow=50)
mat2

set.seed(9999)
mat3 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 2500, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow=50)
mat3

list <- list(mat, mat2, mat3)

number_1_neighbour <- function(x) { 
  check_diff <- diff(x) == 0
  (c(0,check_diff) + c(check_diff,0)) * x
}

# Using function number_1_neighbour over rows and columns to get the number of neighbours in 2 directions that have exactly 1 neighbour.
neigh1_rows_columns <- lapply(list, function(y) sum(t(apply(y, 1, number_1_neighbour)) + apply(y, 2, number_1_neighbour) >= 5))
neigh1_rows_columns
```

This outputs as 0 as it is only looking in 4 directions so I need to be able to look in the diagonal directions too.

Comment: Pleas rewrite your question to not to refer to external csv files. Other users don't have access to them and won't be able to run your code. As I understand, you need a function, which given a 0-1 matrix returns the number of 1s with 5 or more 1s neighbours. In such a case it would be much better to just provide a code which constructs a sample matrix. (e.g. `matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), nrow = 3)` but with more numbers I guess). Also, I see 4 ones (not 3) with 5 or more 1s as neighbours in you matrix. Could you maybe describe which ones do you mean?

Comment: @IaroslavDomin I have provided a reproducible example in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use a small 3x3 matrix to illustrate the method.

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), nrow = 3)
m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    1    1
#> [2,]    0    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    0
```

We'll use the `matrixcalc` package, in particular it's `shift.*` functions to calculate the number of 1-neighbours of each cell. 
Lets take a look at `shif.up(m)` for example.

```
library(matrixcalc)
m_u <- shift.up(m)
m_u
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0
```

It's just `m` lifted up with the bottom row filled with zeros. The main idea here is that for any given indices (i, j), if matrix `m_u` has `1` at this place, it means that this cell in the original matrix has a `1`-neighbour at the bottom. Similar logic applies to all the other shifts. So, to calculate the number `1`-neighbours in all the 8 directions we should sum up all the 8 shift matrices.

```
mat_neighbours <- function(m) {
  # up, down, left, right shifts
  m_u <- shift.up(m)
  m_d <- shift.down(m)
  m_l <- shift.left(m)
  m_r <- shift.right(m)

  # diagonal shifts
  m_ul <- shift.left(m_u)
  m_ur <- shift.right(m_u)
  m_dl <- shift.left(m_d)
  m_dr <- shift.right(m_d)

  m_u + m_d + m_l + m_r +
  m_ul + m_ur + m_dl + m_dr
}

mat_neighbours(m)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    3    3
#> [2,]    4    5    4
#> [3,]    2    3    3
```

Here we can see for example that cell (2, 2) in `m` has 5 `1`-neighbours.

Having this function, now it's easy to calculate the number of `1`-cells with 5 or more `1`-neighbours.

```
sum((m == 1) & mat_neighbours(m) >= 5)
#> [1] 1
```

To apply it to your list of files:

```
library(purrr)
temp %>% 
  map(read.table) %>% 
  map(as.matrix) %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum((. == 1) & mat_neighbours(.) >= 5))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! How would I use this on my list then? Would I need to convert everything in my list to matrices or how would this be done? @IaroslavDomin

Comment: @EJ740 Yes exactly, I've updated the answer. But make sure that every table is converted to a 0-1 numeric matrix. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: To apply this to your list of matrices in the question: `list %>% map_dbl(~sum((. == 1) & mat_neighbours(.) >= 5))`